# Using dotenv module with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) in my `dependencies` of my app. Following the directions, I have a `.env` file and inside is `NODE_ENV=development`.

In my `main.js` file, I'm running a simple `require('dotenv').config();` and yet when I access `process.env`, I'd expect an object and I get `{}`

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Are you using `dotenv` in the server ? or in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

**`dotenv`** only works in the server-side. To use **`.env`** in the client side with webpack, use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack).

1. Install the package, **`yarn add dotenv-webpack -D`** OR **`npm install dotenv-webpack --save`**
2. Add it to your Webpack config file.

   ```
   // webpack.config.js 
   const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
   module.exports = {
     ...
     plugins: [
       new Dotenv({
         path: './.env', // Path to .env file (this is the default) 
         safe: true // load .env.example (defaults to "false" which does not use dotenv-safe) 
       })
     ]
     ...
   };
   ```
3. Add **`.env`** to your **`.gitignore`** file

> **NOTE: Your .env files can include sensitive information. Because of this, `dotenv-webpack` will only expose environment variables that are explicily referenced in your code to your final bundle.**